# Evaluating results from CodedUI Test run in console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I'm in the process of attempting to get a Console Application to run a coded UI test without any dependency on VSTest or Visual Studio or the like installed.

Using the tutorial [here](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2014/03/execute-coded-ui-test-with-console.html) I was able to do so, after adding two DLLs to my solution that were not mentioned in the post (I'm using VS2015, I guess the dependencies have changed):

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.MSAA
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility

The two above DLLs were added to avoid runtime exceptions complaining about those missing DLLs.

Running the Coded UI test as so (as per the tutorial):

```
Playback.Initialize();
CodedUITestInConsoleApp.CodedUI.CodedUITest1 test = new CodedUI.CodedUITest1();
test.CodedUITestMethod1();
Playback.Cleanup();
```

It looks like the test does actually run, but the results are not being recorded as I would expect (writing them to a "TestResults" folder along with screenshots, and the console application does not actually report on the success or failure of the run test.  Any ideas on how to go about reporting the "TestResults" as per running via visual studio, or vstest?

It seems that there are additional caveats to this that I am now experiencing when attempting to run the application on an installation of Windows without Visual Studio installed.  I get the following exception:

[image: exception]

I was hoping it would be as simple as finding that DLL and throwing it as a project reference, but i get the following when i attempt to do that:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here or why I can't add this DLL to my project.  I just want to be able to run these tests from a non VS/test machine.  Is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine the success or failure of the run test by doing the following:

```
class Program
{

    private static bool isInErrorState = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Starting smoke test\n\n");

        Playback.Initialize();
        Playback.PlaybackError += Playback_PlaybackError;

        try
        {
            CodedUITestInConsoleApp.CodedUI.CodedUITest1 test = new CodedUI.CodedUITest1();
            test.CodedUITestMethod1();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!isInErrorState)
                CodedUITestMessage(ex.Message, false);
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }

        if (!isInErrorState)
            CodedUITestMessage("Successful smoke test.", true);

    }

    private static void Playback_PlaybackError(object sender, PlaybackErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Playback.PlaybackError -= Playback_PlaybackError;
        isInErrorState = true;
        CodedUITestMessage("FAILURE running test.", false);
        Playback.StopSession();
    }

    private static void CodedUITestMessage(string message, bool isSuccess)
    {
        if (isSuccess)
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

While this fixed my immediate issue of being able to find the success/failure status of the run test, I am still waiting on feedback on how to accomplish recording "TestResults" as if it were run via MSTest/Visual Studio.